# the_content() is getting null in Preview Debug

Tags: theme-development

I'm not able to edit Page (post-type: page) by Elementor, the Preview could not be loaded theme.

I just created a very simple theme to test, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if (have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
    var_dump(the_content()); // NULL
    }
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It's able to show the content when It's edited by classic editor, but it's not able to edit by `Elementor`, and in the Preview Debugging view is not displaying the content inserted by classic editor.

And it's a new WordPress install, Elementor is the only one enabled plugin

What's missing there?

Comment: `the_content()` _echoes_ the value. It doesn't return anything. So nothing is passed to `var_dump()`.

Comment: Oh man! you're right! weird... So I really don't know why I'm not able to edit page by Elementor now.

Comment: I started a new WordPress project (new installation), my theme is like the code above and Elementor is the only one enabled plugin. But I still not able to edit page by it.

Comment: hey @JacobPeattie, I solved the problem! I didn't add the `wp_footer()`, so Elementor was not able to work properly.

Comment: You should also make sure you have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` between the `<head>` tags.

Comment: Yes I did, thanks @JacobPeattie